# Magento 1.6 sql query for attributes from eav_attribute_option_value table

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I would like to make an SQL query to get the SKU of each product from catalog_product_entity table and the value from the attribute_option_value table for a specific attribute for which I know the attribute code.
I don't know how can I get from the first mentioned table to the second one.
Any ideas? Thanks

Table 1: `catalog_product_entity` (I need the SKU from here):
`entity_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

Table 2: `catalog_product_entity_int` (attribute_id = 128):
`value_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`

Table 1 and Table 2 are connected based on `entity_id`

Table 3:`eav_attribute_option` (attribute_id = 128): 
`option_id`, `attribute_id`, `sort_order`

Table 4: `eav_attribute_option_value` (I need the value from here):
`value_id`, `option_id`, `store_id`, `value`

Table 3 and table 4 are connected based on `option_id`
The problem is that I don't know how to connect table 2 -> table 3(which other tables should I use).

Or am I not using the correct tables to get this information? I need a specific attribute values (this attribute is a dropdown select) for each SKU.

I found this database diagram: http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf

Comment: Can you provide the structure of both the tables ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Also add any queries you have already tried and the associated errors

Answer (score 0):

You know the tables already, you just need to follow Magento's foreign keys and link them all up:

```
SELECT
    e.sku,
    ea.attribute_code,
    eaov.value AS option_value
FROM
    eav_attribute_option_value AS eaov    -- gets the option value
INNER JOIN
    eav_attribute_option AS eao
    ON eao.option_id = eaov.option_id     -- joins the option record
INNER JOIN
    eav_attribute AS ea
    ON ea.attribute_id = eao.attribute_id -- joins the attribute
INNER JOIN
    catalog_product_entity_int AS e_at    -- joins the product attributes
    ON e_at.attribute_id = eao.attribute_id
INNER JOIN
    catalog_product_entity AS e           -- joins the actual product
    ON e.entity_id = e_at.entity_id
-- specify the correct attribute
WHERE
    eaov.store_id = 0
    AND e_at.store_id = 0
    AND eao.attribute_id = 128;
```

Please be aware that this query will generate an enormous amount of data, and will take some time to run.

You'll end up with a list of SKU, attribute code and all of the option values for it. Obviously MySQL is flat in its output, so you'll need to parse the output and make something useful of it with another language probably.